# Wrong values when reading in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, opencl

I want to write a simple OpenCL kernel, but when I read some of the data in the kernel, I get completely different values. The following kernel is a small reproduction.

```
__kernel void kernel( int N, __global float *a, __global float *b, __global float *out ) {               
                    int t_idx = get_global_id(0);                                                                                          
                    size_t gridDim = get_num_groups(0);                                                                                    
                    size_t blockDim = get_local_size(0);                                                                                    
                    for (int t_i = t_idx; t_i < N; t_i += gridDim * blockDim) {                                                    
                        out[t_i] = 2;                                                                                                    
                    }  
                                                                                                                                        
                    if (t_idx == 0) {                                                                                                      
                        out[5] = a[5];                                                                                                 
                    }
}
```

The value `a`is a npy-arrays with double precision values. Since my device does not support `cl_khr_int64` I have to cast it to 32 bit values, before passing it to the kernel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size_a; i++) a[i] = static_cast<float>(a[i]);
```

However, when reading the 6th value of `a` in the kernel above, I get different values when reading `out` after the device-to-host data transfer. When I read values from `c`, which is a float array I did not fetch (or cast), but which I allocated on my host site, everything works fine.

The host-to-device transfer:

```
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, a_d, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * size_a, a, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS) return 0;
```

Im unfortunately out of ideas why the values are wrong as soon I pass them to the kernel. Im thankful for any hints.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major issues I can spot right away:

#### 1. Type system

> The value `a`is a npy-arrays with double precision values. Since my device does not support `cl_khr_int64` I have to cast it to 32 bit values, before passing it to the kernel:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < size_a; i++) a[i] = static_cast<float>(a[i]);
> ```

What you're describing does not match what you're doing in your code - it seems you might have a misunderstanding of C++'s type system. Assuming `a` is declared `double* a;`, the behaviour of the following statement is, roughly:

```
a[i] = static_cast<float>(a[i]);
```

- Read element `i` offset from `a`, a double precision floating point number.
- Convert this to a single-precision floating-point number. (`static_cast`)
- In order to store the result back into `a[i]`, convert the single-precision result into a `double`. (Because that's what `a` says the memory it points to should be treated as.)
- You're then apparently treating the memory at `a`, an array of `double`s as an array of `float`s in your kernel. This almost certainly won't do what you want.

#### 2. Concurrent writes

Given the kernel code

```
                for (int t_i = t_idx; t_i < N; t_i += gridDim * blockDim) {                                                    
                    out[t_i] = 2;                                                                                                    
                }  

                if (t_idx == 0) {                                                                                                      
                    out[5] = a[5];                                                                                                 
                }
```

So, for `t_idx == 0`:

```
out[0] = 2; 
…
out[5] = a[5];
```

and for `t_idx == 5`:

```
out[5] = 2;
```

Two threads are writing to the same memory location `out[5]`, with nothing to serialise the writes. The behaviour of this is undefined.